# R pattern matching with regex for subsetting data.table

Tags: r, regex, data.table, subset

I need to pattern match for use in subsetting a data.table.  I'm not sure how to use escape or whatever is correct syntax with wildcards. MWE here:

```
library(data.table)
code_id <- data.table (c("pat11",
                         "pat11",
                         "pat21",
                         "pat22",
                         "x05ZX",
                         "x05q2",
                         "x05qb",
                         "x05td",
                         "x05xd",
                         "x05qb"))

codes <- c("pat2.", "x05td", "x05q.")

unique (code_id[code_id %in% codes])
```

This returns and empty vector.  I want to subset code_id and keep only the codes "pat21", "pat22", "x05td", "x05q2", and "x05qb" ?  I guess the problem is attempting to do a regex match in the middle of a list of values
How do I need to "escape" or format the "." so it is treated as a wildcard?  Thx. J

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:
The idea common to both is to turn `codes` into an alternation pattern where the separate elements are connected by `|` (Note: I've removed the `.` in `codes` as this is a regex metacharacter)

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
code_id %>% filter(str_detect(V1, paste0(codes, collapse = "|")))
      V1
1: pat21
2: pat22
3: x05q2
4: x05qb
5: x05td
6: x05qb
```

Using `base R`:

```
code_id[grepl(paste0(codes, collapse = "|"), V1)]
      V1
1: pat21
2: pat22
3: x05q2
4: x05qb
5: x05td
6: x05qb
```

Data:

```
codes <- c("pat2", "x05td", "x05q")

code_id <- data.table (c("pat11",
                         "pat11",
                         "pat21",
                         "pat22",
                         "x05ZX",
                         "x05q2",
                         "x05qb",
                         "x05td",
                         "x05xd",
                         "x05qb"))
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, these will certainly work.  I've still got an issue, because in the actual real example I have to match multiple codes so I'm looking for something analogous to  "codes <- c("code1", "grep(x05q.)", "code3")"   so the subsetting is done looking for several strings, one of which happens to have wildcards in it, if that makes any sense.  Thx. J

Comment: Doesn't make complete sense. Please update your question with more realistic examples but combining multiple patterns is not an issue at all

Comment: Have edited the solutions to suit the multiple patterns

Comment: This could be a little stricter (if desired/needed) by including `^` and `$`, such as `paste0("^", paste(codes, collapse="|"), "$")`; this way, it is unlikely to match too much.